# Obtaining cause of connection process error using status /event notice in wpa_supplicant

Tags: linux, android-wifi, wpa, wifi

I am working with wpa_supplicant-0.7.3 .

Some time password entry by a user is wrong and it cause connection error.

I want to know , how to obtain the cause of connection error of wpa_supplicant in normal mode with status or event notice?

Comment: Did you try to run `dmesg` after your try? This shows latest kernel messages.

Comment: I am making one application , in which I want to get events or status for connection error . Its use wpa_ctrl.h functions to interference with wpa_supplicant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The wpa_supplicant logs would indicate a reason code for failure. Look at the wpa_supplicant header file to find the reason corresponding to the code (src/common/defs.h)

Also this link would help
https://supportforums.cisco.com/docs/DOC-14033